# ListViewItem as EditableTextBlock

Tags: c#, wpf

I have a `ListView`. The Itemsource of this `ListView` is populated by a `ObservableCollection`.

What I try to achieve is making the ListViewItems editable. Therefor I downloaded this soluation https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/31592/Editable-TextBlock-in-WPF-for-In-place-Editing

I can make this work as long as my `ListView` doesn't get populated with the `ObservableCollection`.

My Code without `ObservableCollection`:

```
private void ListView1_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Key == Key.F2)
        SetCurrentItemInEditMode(true);
}

private void SetCurrentItemInEditMode(bool EditMode)
{
    ListViewItem m = (ListViewItem)ListView1.SelectedItem;
    EditableTextBlock e = m.Content as EditableTextBlock;
    e.IsInEditMode = EditMode;
}
```

However, when I populate the `ListView` Items with the `ObservableCollection` it doesn't work.

```
MyFiles m = (MyFiles)ListView1.SelectedItem;
EditableTextBlock e = m.FileName as EditableTextBlock;
e.IsInEditMode = EditMode;
```

MyFiles contains (FileName, FileCreation and FileIcon). I want to convert the FileName selected `ListViewItem` to the `EditableTextBlock` control.

Thank you for your help.

P.S. I'm pretty new to WPF so please apologize if my question is stupid.

Comment: That's pretty poor solution you have linked, it looks like the guy come from winforms and haven't heard yet about data templates. Making something editable in WPF is very easy, you just have to supply proper template and use two-way bindings. Can't find an easy duplicate, see e.g. [this tutorial](http://www.wpf-tutorial.com/listview-control/listview-with-gridview/).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should define an `ItemTemplate` with an `EditableTextBlock` in your XAML markup. Note the bindings:

```
<ListView x:Name="ListView1">
    <ListView.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <StackPanel>
                <local:EditableTextBlock Text="{Binding FileName}" IsInEditMode="{Binding IsInEditMode}" />
            </StackPanel>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListView.ItemTemplate>
</ListView>
```

Then you should add an `IsInEditMode` property to your `MyFiles` class and set this one to true whenever you want to put the item into edit mode:

```
private void SetCurrentItemInEditMode(bool EditMode)
{
    MyFiles obj = ListView1.SelectedItem as MyFiles;
    obj.IsInEditMode = EditMode;
}
```

For this to work, your `MyFiles` class should implement the `INotifyPropertyChanged` interface and raise the `PropertyChanged` event in the setter of the `IsInEditMode` property as explained on MSDN: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.inotifypropertychanged(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: Thank you! Workes like a charm. And as a bonus I finally understood inotifypropertychanged. :-)